# Issue with array Searching element

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to search an array with the inputted value from the user. For example, if the user wants to search for the number 10 in the array, it will find the location of the element 10 and print it out. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Please help me. Thank you.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DeleteElements {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int del = 0;
    boolean check;
    int intArray[] = {10,20,30,40,50};

    System.out.print("The array consists of: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(intArray[i] + ", ");
    }

    System.out.print("\nWhich number should be removed for the list? ");
    del = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number to delete: " + del);

    if(intArray.length == del){
      check = true;
      System.out.println("Good");
    }else{ 
      check = false;
      System.out.println("Bad");
    }

    while (check == true){
      for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        if (intArray[i] == del){
          System.out.println("Number found at index: " + i);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Number not found!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(intArray.length == del)`, what do you expect with this line ??

Comment: How do you do this with a while statement?

Comment: You're checking for equality between the length of the array and the number to delete => doesn't make any sense to me. On the contrary, the following does: `if (intArray[i] == del)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this

```
  if(intArray.length == del){
      check = true;
      System.out.println("Good");
    }else{ 
      check = false;
      System.out.println("Bad");
    }
```

and put after that this

```
 for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
    if (intArray[i] == del){
      System.out.println("Number found at index: " + i);
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Number not found!");
```

So the full implementation should be like :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DeleteElements {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int del = 0;
    int intArray[] = {10,20,30,40,50};

    System.out.print("The array consists of: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(intArray[i] + ", ");
    }

    System.out.print("\nWhich number should be removed for the list? ");
    del = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number to delete: " + del);



      for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        if (intArray[i] == del){
          System.out.println("Number found at index: " + i);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Number not found!");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code will never leave the `while(check == true)` statement. I would get rid of the array length checking `if` statement since it's redundant. When you do a `for(int i=0; i < intArray.lenght; i++)` you are already making sure you won't check out of bounds. Besides: **why are you checking if the input is equal to the array length?**

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
if (intArray[i] == del) {
System.out.println("You found that number");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to check with this:

```
if(intArray.length == del){
  check = true;
  System.out.println("Good");
}else{ 
  check = false;
  System.out.println("Bad");
}
```

but i don think you need it

the condition 
    intArray.length == del 
is always false for this example so you won't get to enter the loop at all

Comment: Please add some more details to the answer as it doesn't actually solve the problem.